# Multiple Trips to the Db

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have those group of CheckBox Lists and Repeaters (about 8 controls needed to be loaded from my db) and for each control, I have a method in my DataAccess Layer to select the information and get it back to my control.

But There's a page that I need all those 8 controls to be loaded on the same time .. so each method will be a trip to the db and I understand that's what affects the performance. So can I have like a new method to create the connection and open it, then I can call multiple methods to access the db and load the info then close the connection at the end.

Any ideas if those 8 connections are okay for performance ? and what do you think about this idea and how can it be applied in a practical way ?

Comment: In general you suppose to make one connection to the database. Make as many calls as you need and disconnect at the end.

Comment: what about retrieving all result into one DataSet by one query

Comment: I might be misunderstanding or over-simpliying your problem, but have you looked at the [formview control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227992.aspx)?  This has been really helpful for me when loading controls with information from a DB.  Disregard if this isn't what you're looking for =)

Comment: I actually need 8 separate lists and each lists gets information from a separate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the native SqlClient to access your database, using the exact same connection string, they will share a connection pool. . By default, connection pooling is enabled in ADO.NET. Unless you explicitly disable it, the pooler optimizes the connections as they are opened and closed in your application.

So based on your question if you do:

```
using (SqlConnection...)
{
 // all your data calls
}
```

or 7 separate calls, each opening and closing (or using "using") as @Tim Coker mentioned, any differences in performance will be minimal

**Edit**: There are some dated articles on MSDN that do say "Open a connection as late as possible and close it as soon as possible", so you could do a rapid series of method calls that each open and quickly close the connection, but again, will be sharing the same pool anyway.

Comment: @Chris Marisic .. I'm sorry I appreciate that you're trying to help. But actually all what you're doing is down-voting guys trying to help and in the end confusing me! .. and I've heard before something about the connection pooling and to have all the same ConnectionString! .. If you think those are wrong answers, Please prove that by a right answer not by the negative scores!

Comment: @IKashef you already know the correct answer, which is to improve your application design. Even 10 concurrent users, you're talking about 80+ round trips continuously for that single page, not including anything else from your application. Being told "it's good enough" is just incorrect.

Comment: @Chris Marisic .. Well I was originally asking about how to improve my design and how to make this connections take less time, yet with a good design and architecture .. so any ideas ? .. and it's better to improve than saying it's good enough still, they weren't making things up, so I think DownVoting was unfair here

Answer (score 1):

Unless your app is going to be on a high-traffic website, I wouldn't worry about it until it becomes an issue.  It's relatively simple to go back and fix it later should problems arise, but this sounds like a case of premature optimization, to be honest.

Comment: -1 intelligent design around the limitation of round trip calls to a database is not premature optimization it is good architecture design. There's a difference between a couple, and 8. This is also 8 specifically for this scenario, that doesn't include if there are any other requests going on behind the scenes like `GetRoles()`, `LogVisit()` etc.

Comment: You're assuming the dat intensive nature of his calls, but if you feel like downvoting go ahead man

Answer (score 0):

If the data is read-only, you could cache it.

Then, each trip to the database will only be made once.

Comment: well, caching won't be good for me. the data might change anytime and my front-end would be displaying the same old cached data!

Answer (score 0):

There is very little overhead when you open and close a connection, so you should not worry about that.

Comment: Well, yes and no.  Actually there is a lot of overhead which is why connection pooling is automatically implemented in most architectures.